Not able to connect to AASX server
I have a adminshellio image running on docker and I have created a aasx server on localhost. However in the aasx package explorer app whenever I try to connect to the server this message appears.

Any help?
Thanks :)
On docker it says it is running fine:

Even the example shown is correctly loaded to the server:

But for some reason whenever I try to connect to the server via AASX package explorer it does not work.

Same problem here! @Rafael did you manage to find any solution?
